# E2E testing Ionic App with Crosswalk, Appium & Protractor Not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, appium, crosswalk-runtime, e2e-testing

Lately our Ionic app grew to a phase where we would like to add end to end automation tests. Problem arises when we try to use appium and our app is built upon crosswalk.

A quick search around finds that one requires to have the crosswalk-webdriver in order for the tests to work with crosswalk, but it is basically non existent/non compatible for windows/mac.
Given this is the situation I was wondering:

Does anyone know how to solve this issue or perhaps a different e2e automating testing framework that does work with crosswalk thus enabling us to test our Ionic app?

Is there a workaround to release the app to android platform once with crosswalk and once without in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround found for now, can finally start developing e2e tests with appium, crosswalk, protractor ionic.

Thanks to piotrekkmt post on appiums github (https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4597), he added a  web driver supporting crosswalk with a short explanation for mac. If you got a mac, this could solve the inability to perform protractor tests with appium when working with crosswalk:

https://github.com/piotrekkmt/chromedriver-appium

Comment: @@Ophir Are you using protractor with Appium for functional testing? I was trying to automate my crosswalk app build in ionic using only appium but not able to do so. Any solution around this?

Comment: Hi @SurajGupta, Yes, using protractor with Appium. Not familiar with a solution other than this..

Comment: Ok @Ophir do you came across solution where people are using only appium and keeping their functional test project independent of developement project. My requirements are such that I need to change certain configuration files on CI env while test execution. But using protractor, code would be basically in Javascript (heard this)that I wont be able to use for file modification since Javascript wont allow me to do so.. Then I need to move to nodejs for all this and I dont need want to increase complication. Let me know if you come across any such articles/post which could fulfill my requirement

Comment: Hi Ophir..I was trying to automate the ionic app but facing some issues while trying to run..Can you guide me through step by step process..any blog or references..Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Suraj, Since this post I've made some major changes to my app which caused me to abandon e2e tests, so I do not remember any part of the process. If I'll decide to try again, I'll post an update.
Sorry

Comment: @@Ophir.. Can we automate windows cross platform app using protractor+Appium. If yes then how it works?

Comment: Hi Suraj, Since this post I've made some major changes to my app which caused me to abandon e2e tests, so I do not remember any part of the process. If I'll decide to try again, I'll post an update. Sorry